# listing arraylist items inside another arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I just used the 
`ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`
method for the first time and the output wasn't exactly in the way I wanted it to be.

I'm trying to make lists of different students and sorting them by what grade they're in. But, I am also trying to have a list that displays *all* the students, regardless of their grade. So this is the code that I was using:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> allStudents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList <String> gradeNines = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> gradeTens = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> gradeElevens = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> gradeTwelves = new ArrayList();

boolean firstSelection = true;

public void grade(String a, String b, ArrayList c)
{

    a = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() + "";

    if (a.equals(b))
    {
        studentOutput.setText("");
        int x = 0; 
        for (int indexNum = 0; indexNum < c.size(); indexNum++) 
        { 
             x = indexNum + 1; 
             studentOutput.append(num + ". " + c.get(indexNum) + "\n"); 
        }
    }
}   

 private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String studentGrade = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() + "";

    String all = "All Grades";
    String nine = "Grade Nine";
    String ten = "Grade Ten";
    String eleven = "Grade Eleven";
    String twelve = "Grade Twelve";

    if (firstSelection)
    {
         Collections.addAll(allStudents, gradeNines, gradeTens, gradeElevens, gradeTwelves);
         Collections.addAll(gradeNines, "Oscar", "Justin",....);
         Collections.addAll(gradeTens, "Austin", "Jacob", "Evie"....);
         Collections.addAll(gradeElevens, "Olivia", "Elizabeth"...);
         Collections.addAll(gradeTwelves, "Ryan", "Jade"...);
         firstSelection = false;
    }

    grade(studentGrade, all, allStudents);
    grade(studentGrade, nine, gradeNines);
    grade(studentGrade, ten, gradeTens);
    grade(studentGrade, eleven, gradeElevens);
    grade(studentGrade, twelve, gradeTwelves);
```

But the way this outputted, it was like:

> 1. [Oscar, Justin] 2. [Austin, Jacob, Evie] 3. [Olivia, Elizabeth] 4. [Ryan, Jade]

Is there a way to make it so that it outputs so that it shows each name individually like:

> 1. Oscar 2. Justin 3. Austin 4. Jacob ...

Comment: Are you set all the `ArrayList` values to the `studentOutput`?

Comment: You can use nested loop to get your desired output because of `allStudents` is a `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`

Comment: [This may help you to iterate through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470705/iterate-through-an-arraylist-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: just dont put allStudents list to grade() function. because it is list of lists

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, these type of "grouping" problems are better handled using a `Map` (HashMap or an ordered implementation). 
You could have the grades as the `key` and the list of student names as the values. That would feel as a better and easier way to handle collection data than a nested ArrayList.

Regarding your question,

> Is there a way to make it so that it outputs so that it shows each name individually

No. These are separate ArrayLists. You will need to add/display them together, explicitly.

Further, I suggest you use the `groupingBy` function of `Streams` in Java 8. That will fit your use case very well.

With `Streams`, you could choose to display all items together OR group them by grades and display based on the chosen crteria(grade).

See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30202075/599851